# What does it mean $('td:gt(-2)')?

Tags: jquery

I've read [article about :gt jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and i don't actually understand what does it mean "..counting backwards from the last element." `$( "td:gt(-2)" )` ? I don't understand why last cell satisfies this condition.

Comment: A demo of how it works http://jsfiddle.net/gEwa8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means

> Select the cell (`td`) that comes after the penultimate cell (`:gt(-2)`)

which is only satisfied by the last of the selected cells.

In general, the [*greater than (`:gt`)* selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) with *negative indexes* is useful if you don't know how many cells there are, so you cannot start counting from the beginning.

Have a look at this example with indexes:

```
<tr>           <!--   index from start      index from end -->
    <td>a</td> <!--         0                     -4       -->
    <td>b</td> <!--         1                     -3       -->
    <td>c</td> <!--         2                     -2       -->
    <td>d</td> <!--         3                     -1       -->
</tr>
```

Here are some selector examples:

```
$('td:gt(0)')  // selects b, c, d
$('td:gt(-4)') // selects b, c, d

$('td:gt(1)')  // selects c, d
$('td:gt(-3)') // selects c, d

$('td:gt(3)')  // selects d
$('td:gt(-2)') // selects d
```

---

In this situation, a more appropriate selector would be `:eq`:

```
$('td:eq(-1)') // selects the last cell
```

Answer (score 0):

according to jquery's api doc (http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) "gt" stands for "greater than". A negative index means you're counting backwards from the end.

So, your code is selecting the last element of the table.